# Python - Patching Module Functions?

Tags: python, mocking

I'm trying to test a method in a class that uses a function imported from another module, I'd like to patch this imported module to simplify my testing but I can't seem to figure it out, I've tried all sorts of paths for the patch but with not luck.

As a simplified example say I have a project structure like this:

[image: Dir Structure]

In the Adders folder I have an `AddFour` class and a `Util` module that look like this, you give `AddFour` a value and it adds four to it from the `giveFour` method

```
# Util.py
def giveFour():
    return 4

#AddFour.py
from Adders.Util import giveFour

class AddFour:

def add(self, value):
    return value + giveFour()
```

I then have a test where for sake of example I'm trying to patch the `giveFour` function to instead return 5

I've done some reading and the common suggestion is patch where the object is looked up but I can't get it right

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from Adders.AddFour import AddFour

class AddFour_Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('Adders.AddFour.giveFour')
    def give_five(mock_give):
        mock_give.return_value = 5


    def test_add_four(self):
        test_class = AddFour() # Should now add 5?
        result = test_class.add(5)
        self.assertEqual(result, 10)
```

If this is possible could anyone point me in the right direction? I feel I'm missing something really obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
class AddFour_Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('adders.AddFour.giveFour')
    def test_addfour(self, give_four):
        give_four.return_value = 5 
        add4 = AddFour()
        result = add4.add(5)
        self.assertEqual(result, 10)
```

You want to decorate the test method where your mocked function is being called, because the mock is only active within that method.